# Can't display retrieved data in C# DGV

Tags: c#, mysql

I have 2 DGV in my C# application, then i write my code. Code for both DGV exactly same, but only 1 DGV can display the data. Why?
Anyone can help? if want to see the output, can email me: candy.9639@gmail.com
PS: my reputation is not enough to allow me post image here.

C#:

```
 private void LoadData()
    {
        string MyConnectionString = "Server=31.220.XX.XX;Database=XXXXX_fyp;Uid=XXXXX_eee2110;Pwd=myPW;";

        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
        MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        connection.Open();

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT tablenum, name, quantity FROM ordertable where tablenum = '1' & status = '1'";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adap.Fill(ds);
        kitchen1_dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT tablenum, name, quantity FROM ordertable where tablenum = '16' & status = '1'";
        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
        adap.Fill(ds2);
        kitchen2_dgv.DataSource = ds2.Tables[0].DefaultView;

        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Clone();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check if both queries return any data. It could be that one of the queries doesn't return data.

Comment: Can you debug to see if the second adap has the updated cmd, if not, using adap.SelectCommand to update it. Put mooore breakpoints!

Comment: You don't have to clone the connection.  remove connection.Clone();

Comment: i found that "Select * from ordertable where tablenum = '16' " can use. But, when i change to "Select * from ordertable where tablenum = '16' & status = '1' ", the data didn't display. Anyone know why?

Comment: @RyanChu do you know why?

Comment: Would have to see the data in the tables to know why. And please use standard SQL `AND`, not `&` even though MySQL allows it. Also don't quote numbers if the fields are really numbers as they should be.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen in the table, field included: tablenum(varchar(40)), name(varchar(40)), quantity(varchar(40)), status(int). And the data (16, Carbonara Spaghetti, 3, 1)