# MySQL Inner Join Syntax Error in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Anyone know why got syntax error? I think there are no reserve words inside right?

C# Command

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ordertable._name, ordertable.quantity, food_menu.food_price, beverage_menu.beverage_price" +
                         "FROM ordertable" +
                         "INNER JOIN food_menu ON ordertable._name = food.foodname" +
                         "INNER JOIN beverage_menu ON beverage_menu.beverage_name' = ordertable._name" +
                         "WHERE ordertable.tablenum = '1'";
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'JOIN food_menu ON ordertable._name = food.foodnameINNER JOIN
>   beverage_menu ON be' at line 1

Comment: You don't need to use single quote on `beverage_menu.beverage_name'`. Also `ordertable.tablenum` is character typed? Also you need a white space at the end of your each line.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing spaces. At the moment your query will be like `FROM ordertableINNER JOIN food_menu ...`. You could use the multiline syntax to make it simpler

```
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT ordertable._name, ordertable.quantity, food_menu.food_price, beverage_menu.beverage_price
                         FROM ordertable
                         INNER JOIN food_menu ON ordertable._name = food_menu.foodname
                         INNER JOIN beverage_menu ON beverage_menu.beverage_name = ordertable._name
                         WHERE ordertable.tablenum = 1";
```

Comment: okay.. i found the problem and i solved it. But why there are no data displayed in my DGV?

Comment: @woo4896 That is another question and impossible to answer without seeing code and database contents. You can ask another question if you have problems with it.

Comment: i face this problem before. When i put "SELECT * FROM ordertable WHERE tablenum = '1' ", DGV show data. But, when i put "SELECT * FROM ordertable WHERE tablenum='1' & status = '1' ", there are no data shown  in DGV. But i dk why.

Comment: i asked before this question. look this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085159/cant-display-retrieved-data-in-c-sharp-dgv

Answer (score 0):

Remove unnecessary concatenation from string, you are getting an error because your query needs some spaces which you have not specified before join.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ordertable._name, 
                          ordertable.quantity, 
                          food_menu.food_price,
                          beverage_menu.beverage_price 
                   FROM  ordertable
                   INNER JOIN food_menu 
                         ON ordertable._name = food.foodname
                   INNER JOIN beverage_menu 
                         ON beverage_menu.beverage_name = ordertable._name
                   WHERE ordertable.tablenum = 1";
```